# How does Rails yield to multiple block in the erb templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yield

How does rails get away with the following in an .erb file?

```
<%= yield :sidebar %>
<%= yield :other_bar %>
<%= yield :footer %>
```

How are they able to yield multiple times in the same context to different symbols? Is this some kind of rails magic?

I'm totally familiar with:

```
def some_method(arg1, arg2, &block)
 yield(:block)
end
```

To my knowledge following doesn't work:

```
def some_incorrect_method(arg1, &block1, &block2)
 yield(:block1)
 yield(:block2)
end
```

So how are they doing it? How do they make it work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They are passing a symbol into yield...

```
yield :symbol
```

...not yielding to a different block.

It works more like this:

```
def some_method(arg1, arg2, &block)
  yield(:some_symbol1)
  yield(:some_symbol2)
end

some_method do |symbol|
  case symbol
  when :some_symbol1
     # do A
  when :some_symbol2
     # do B
  else
     # unrecognised symbol?
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for ?